# Arduino core for ATMega16u2

Tags: core-libraries

I've looked around a ton so it's probably not available but does anyone know if there is a usable core for the ATMega16u2 (the chip the Uno and Due uses for USB to Serial). I have a project I was going to use the 32u4 for but they aren't really available for several months and the 16u2 has all the functionality that I would really need.

Comment: ["171 in stock"](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640)

Comment: I need the actual IC, NOT a board that already has it.

Comment: :O I... I don't think I've ever seen so many 0s before... Newark has a few -MUs, but I think someone bought up the world's supply of -AUs.

Comment: Yup :( Was very dissapointed that basically no one has them...

Comment: I think it's pretty much the same as the 32u4 but has less flash memory and less RAM. I think avr-gcc handles the RAM part. As for the flash memory, just copy and modify the atmega32u4 section in boards.txt to handle that.

Comment: I forgot about the bootloader. But I think you can just recompile it for the atmega16u2 without many, if any, changes.

Comment: Or use a programmer and forgo the bootloader entirely.

Comment: Don't need the bootloader actually. As long as it can be programmed via an ISP I'm good.

Comment: A thought just occurred to me. If a 16U2 will do, then why not use a 16U4 instead? All you'd need to change is the amount of flash available. And DigiKey has a few hundred of those in stock in -AU.

Answer (score 1):

As @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams said, a 16u4 is virtually identical with a 32u4, so you can use a Leonardo or Micro core with a tiny modification to boards.txt. A 16u2 is a rather different animal, with fewer timers, many fewer pins, and no A/D converter, so you’d have to do a fair amount of editing to obtain a usable Arduino core.

That said, if you’re reasonably fluent in C++, building your own Arduino core is not very difficult, and I found it an instructive exercise. If you care about getting your project up as quickly as possible and not get sidetracked, however, go with the 16u4.