# Porting Arduino for ATMEGA16U2

Tags: arduino-ide, usb, arduino-leonardo, bootloader, core-libraries

I have a bunch of `ATMEGA16U2` in my drawer and I need to make a small production of custom boards with Arduino-based firmware.

After a Google search I learn the `ATMEGA16U2` is often hosted on the Arduino boards as USB converter and there some hacks to reprogram it. But this is not my goal... I'm trying to understand how to compile and download the firmware using Arduino IDE and this MCU as target.

I guess (also from [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/arduino-core-for-atmega16u2) old question) I need to update both the bootloader and the specification of the board.

Questions:

1. before reinvent the wheel are you aware of a ready-to-use porting for `ATMEGA16U2`? I did a search find nothing relevant
2. what is the official guide to update the files (bootloader + boards.txt) to support a new MCU? I find forum threads only

Comment: this could help https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54484/adding-a-custom-board-to-the-arduino-ide/60660#60660 using AVR core as referred core

Comment: @Juraj thanks I'm reading the answer - but as said it's again a public forum... where is the official documentation that explains in detail each step?

Comment: there is a link in the answer to the official doc, but there is no tutorial

Comment: @Juraj I saw but it's about `arduino-cli`. If it's correct I'm going to study it :)

Comment: Arduino IDE uses the arduino-cli

Comment: Ok, because it's not installed by default I didn't understand that.

Comment: I don't agree with the decision of closing the question. Actually, my questions are precise and different than what reported in the other answers.